# Magento 1.9 Recently viewed products not displaying

Tags: magento1.9.3, recently-viewed

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This code suppose to output the **recently viewed products** on category page or product page (by inserting the code in .phtml files). and this has been always working for me on my Magento sites.

However I have experienced that for one site (Magento 1.9.3.3), this code isn't working at all. and for this site, the **widget** to show recently viewed product doesn't work either.

Any ideas what can cause the "recently viewed products" isn't working?

Comment: This code looks good, not sure why not working for you.

Comment: @SohelRana Can it be the custom themes that cause the issue, or this code will output the recently viewed products regardless the theme?

Comment: This code is not depends on theme. But if your module overwrite template or something this would be problem.

Comment: @SohelRana This code is working now, without I've done anythong. It's wierd. Can 
 cron job effect this?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether your static block is whitelisted in admin panel, this could be one of the reasons the widget content might not be showing up in the frontend.

Refer the below link

[Static Block Whitelist issue](http://mydons.com/resolved-magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issue/)

Comment: Just checked. Everything is set to allowed under system -> permissions -> blocks