# Magento 1.9 How does Magento record "recently viewed products"?

Tags: magento-1.9, recently-viewed

I'm trying to diagnose an issue with the feature **Recently Viewed Products**. I wonder where does Magento save Recently Viewed Products information, in *Database*? or in *Session*?  if the information is saved in Database, which table does it get saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **report_viewed_product_index** table, where magento store information when visit product.

Following block is responsible for return collection:

> app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php

Check following class how save:

> app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Event/Observer.php

```
/**
 * View Catalog Product action
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer
 */
public function catalogProductView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!$this->_enabledReports) {
        return $this;
    }

    $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

    Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')
        ->setProductId($productId)
        ->save()
        ->calculate();

    return $this->_event(Mage_Reports_Model_Event::EVENT_PRODUCT_VIEW, $productId);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. is it possible that you can help me with this question too? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/272651/26668